# kubernetes azure nodes exceed max volume count

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pvc

I have kubernetes cluster of 4 nodes. according to this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-limits/
azure should have limit of 16 pv per node.

```
Microsoft Azure Disk Storage    16
```

So I should have 64 volumes available.
Although i can create only 16. Trying to create 17th gives me an error

```
0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) exceed max volume count.
```

What could be the reason of this?

Comment: are you using azure files or disks for the PV?

Comment: we are using azure disk

Comment: Which VM size do you use?

Comment: each node is -- Standard E2s v3 (2 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)

Comment: Kubernetes:
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this issue, the VM size you use is [Standard E2s_v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-memory#esv3-series), the max disk count for each VM is 4, so the most available disk count for your cluster which has 4 nodes is 16. So even if the max disk count limit is 64 for the Kubernetes cluster which has 4 nodes, but you cluster only can use 16 disks at most.

Then the solution is simple, use more nodes or choose another VM size which allows more disk count.

Comment: this can't be it, I have the same issue, after deleting volumes I still get the same issue

Comment: @PvdL Post a question and provide more details, it will be helpful to figure out the certain issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change from Azure Disk to Azure Files as the default Storage Class. If your applications can use Azure Files then you aren't limited by the Disks per Node

You can also set the storage class to Azure Files in your persistent volume claim